# Azurite Blob storage in dockerfile

Tags: azure, docker

I'm creating my development environment in Docker and due to need of Azure Storage service I want to use Azurite as local Azure Storage service.

When I try to do

```
RUN azurite-blob &
```

it just runs and no effect is done by this command. I also tried echo this command to file and run as script, but the result was the same.

When I run the same command on docker container it starts normally and creates various catalogs for azurite.

So the question is how to make azurite working in background in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not make a command to work in background inside the build steps of the dockerfile, since every steps will run in a seperate layer and will removed when the step finished.

you may use:

- `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` to achieve that (aka run it in the runtime not build)

**UPDATE**

based on your comment:

create `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/azurite &

exec "$@"
```

you need to set it as executable first , in Dockerfile:

```
COPY script.sh script.sh
RUN chmod +x script.sh
```

then you can use `bash` as your command for interactive mode

Comment: Maybe I did not mention that I run container as interactive so, you don't have to install anything on PC but docker. 
When I use `ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/azurite" ]` it runs but I'm no longer able to use bash in container. 
When I use `[ "/usr/bin/azurite", "&" ]` it still does not run in background. Maybe because CMD or ENTRYPOINT overrides interactive mode? Not sure, but I used many combinations and still does not solve my problem.

Comment: It's working now, Thanks.

I added `ENTRYPOINT [ "/azurite.sh" ]` in dockerfile and also I had to run 
`docker run -it [...] /bin/bash` to make it work